# Missing vertical line in table

Tags: tables, rules

I'm new to LaTeX and learning quite quickly thanks to this site, among others that teach me quick fixes for my mistakes, but I can't seem to find a fix for this, I'm not able to draw the right border for this table, this is the code, am I doing something wrong?

```
\begin{center}
\begin{tabular}{|rccccc|}
\hline
  1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5 \\
  1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5 \\
  1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5 \\
\hline
\end{tabular}
\end{center}
```

(package `tabu` is loaded in top of the document).

[image]

Edit:
Problem solved... The solution was simple: I defined 6 rows and only filled 5, so I had to add & 6 at the end of each line, before \, like this:

```
\begin{center}
\begin{tabular}{|rccccc|}
\hline
  1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5 & 6\\
  1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5 & 6\\
  1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5 & 6\\
\hline
\end{tabular}
\end{center}
```

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) You should remove one `c` in `\begin{tabular}{|rccccc|}`, you are declaring one more column than you are using.